# UI Router is not injecting resolved value into views at the same level

Tags: angularjs, state, angular-ui-router

I have the following state configuration:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('customer', {
    url: '/customers',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/main.tpl.html',
    views: {
      'list': {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/list.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl as ctrl'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      customerList: function ($stateParams, CustomerResource) {
        console.log('trying to resolve');
        var list = CustomerResource.list($stateParams);
        return list;
      }
    }
  })
```

Here is the main template:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div ui-view="list" class="col-lg-4"/>

    <div ui-view="details" class="col-lg-8"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I see on the console that angular is trying to resolve the dependency. But this dependency is never injected into the controller under `views`. What am I doing wrong here?

P.S. When I move `views` to some child state like `customer.test` the resolved dependency is injected as expected:

```
 .state('customer.test', {
    url: '/test',
    views: {
      'list@customer': {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/list.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl as ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFaIDCXvFKxgRKsQYppP?p=preview)

The problem here is not with resolve, but with the injection of the main template. This should be the state definition:

```
  .state('customer', {
    url: '/customers',
    //templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/main.tpl.html',
    views: {
      '': { 
        templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/main.tpl.html'
      },
      'list@customer': {
        templateUrl: 'app/components/customer/templates/list.tpl.html',
        controller: 'ListCtrl as ctrl'
      }
    },
    resolve: {
      customerList: function ($stateParams, CustomerResource) {
        console.log('trying to resolve');
        var list = CustomerResource.list($stateParams);
        return list;
      }
    }
  })
```

so, with these in play:

```
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'customerList', function ($scope, customerList) { 
  $scope.resolved =  customerList
}])
.factory('CustomerResource', function(){
  return {
    list: function(params){return "Hello world"}
  }
})
```

we can see that list view like this:

```
<div>
  <h3>list view</h3>
  {{resolved}}
</div>
```

will show *Hello world*

Check it [here in action](http://plnkr.co/edit/KFaIDCXvFKxgRKsQYppP?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this happens? I thought the `templateUrl` should belong to the state...

Comment: Yes, I know why ;) Check it here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#views-override-states-template-properties *"Views override state's template properties"*... ***"If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and templateProvider will be ignored"*** hope it helps ;)

Comment: Ok, now it's clear. I thought they will be merged and not overridden. Thanks again

Comment: Great if that helped ;) Enjoy mighty UI-Router, sir!