# Why controller does not work in UI-router of angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

When I try to load the "test" state or any of these state, controllers does not affect. Template are changed perfectly but no data comes from the mentioned controller in state configuration.

And I did not use ng-controller directive any where.

```
myApp.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
$stateProvider.state('task',
    {
        url:'/task',
        controller:"TasksController",
        views:{
            "sidebar":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskcreateform.html'},
            "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskgrid.html'}
        }

})
.state('notes',
    {
        url:'/notes',
        controller:"TasksController",
        views:{
            "sidebar":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskcreateform.html'},
            "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskgrid.html'}
        }


})
.state('test',
    {
        url:'/test/:id',
        controller:"AtTestController",
        views:{
            "sidebar":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskupdateform.html'},
            "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/test.html'}
        }



})
.state('edittask',
    {
        url:'/edittask/:editabletaskid',
        controller:"TasksController",
        views:{
            "sidebar":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskupdateform.html'},
            "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskgrid.html'}
        },
        resolve:{

            editabletask: function($stateParams,Task){
                 Task.get({id:$stateParams.editabletaskid},
                        function(response){
                            return response;
                        },
                        function(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        });
            }
        }

  });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('task');

});
```

And My one Controller is :

```
////////////////////TEST CONTROLLER/////////////
myApp.controller("AtTestController",function($scope){

 $scope.appname="Rahul Apps";

 $scope.name=function(){
    console.log($scope.appname);
   }
  $scope.name();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

The point is:

> Any **Controller** always belongs to **view**, not to *state*

E.g. instead of this:

```
// because we used views, this controller is now skipped
controller:"AtTestController",
views:{
    "sidebar":{templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskupdateform.html'},
    "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/test.html'}
}
```

we need that:

```
views:{
    "sidebar":{
       templateUrl:'/partial/task/taskupdateform.html',
       controller:"AtTestController",
    },
    "content":{templateUrl:'/partial/test.html'}
}
```

Check the doc for the difference:

#### [Views override state's template properties](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#views-override-states-template-properties)

> If you define a views object, your state's templateUrl, template and templateProvider will be ignored. So in the case that you need a parent layout of these views, you can define an abstract state that contains a template, and a child state under the layout state that contains the 'views' object.

Comment: Actually,I also tried to use ng-controller, but when my state changes, the controller dose not updated to desired controller of the mentioned state in url. In this plunker UI-router test project I didn't use ng-controller. But it works as expected . [link]http://embed.plnkr.co/EzT6ZxWYnopUQMJmHtY5/preview

Comment: NO ng-controller... I moved the controller declaration from state level to view level... can you see that?

Comment: Check the working plunker http://stackoverflow.com/q/32309724/1679310 related to similar quesiton

Comment: Bro Would you please clarify a little bit ?

Comment: Well, that's why I gave you links to doc and to an example. But let's try this: You can declare `controller` on the state level, if there is no `views : {}` object. It is just a syntactic sugar for us, when the controller and templateUrl are internally converted into `views: { '' : { controller... }}` ... i.e. unnamed view is injected into views. But if you've started to declare `views : {}` yourself, now you have to also declare each controller for each template. Does it help a bit?

Comment: If it is now clear, great. Enjoy mighty UI-Router ;)