# UI-Router Multiple Views Single Controller not work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, state, ionic-view

I would like to use one controller defined in views, but the `$scope` does not define anything. Is there a way to do this? Please share a simple example in order to understand.

I have this index.html

```
<body ng-app="ehc">
<h1>{{home}}+{{a}}+{{b}}</h1>
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" delegate-handle="left">
    <!-- Left menu -->
    <ion-side-menu side="left" is-enabled="true">

            <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">AAA</ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <div class="list">
                    <div class="item item-divider">
                        Candy Bars
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ion-content>


    </ion-side-menu>

    <ion-side-menu-content edge-drag-threshold="true" drag-content="true">
        <!-- Main content, usually <ion-nav-view> -->
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" >
            <ion-nav-title>
                <h2>hello world title *{{home}}*</h2>
            </ion-nav-title>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>

            <ion-view>
                <ion-content class="has-header">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <div ui-view="a"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-50">
                            <div ui-view="b"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </ion-content>
            </ion-view>


</ion-side-menu-content>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/a.html">
   <ion-view>
       <ion-content class="has-header">
           **{{a}}**
       </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templates/b.html">
   <ion-view>
       <ion-content class="has-header">
           **{{b}}**
       </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
</script>
</body>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

And this is my model definition **app.js**

```
var app = angular.module("ehc", ["ionic"])
.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

  $stateProvider.state('Home', {
    url: '/',
    controller: "HomeCtrl",
    //template:"<ion-header-bar></ion-header-bar><ion-content><h1>hello dal AngularJs</h1></ion-content>",
    views: {
      "a": {
        templateUrl: 'templates/a.html'
      },
      "b": {
        templateUrl: 'templates/b.html'
      }
    }
  });


}).controller("HomeCtrl", ["$scope", "$ionicSideMenuDelegate",
  "$routeParams", "config", "$q", "$http"], function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $routeParams, config, $q, $http) {


  $scope.toggleLeft = function () {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };

  //carico le lingue e il menu
  console.log("AAAAAAAAAAAA");
  $scope.home = "Pippo";
  $scope.a="XAX";
  $scope.b="XBX";
})
```

console is empty and also the scope in html template. Please if you have the solution, use very simple example.

I've read here and I thought it worked [Rakrap Jaknap answered on 2015-04-17 08:01](http://www.ngroutes.com/questions/1c54fd3/ui-router-multiple-views-single-controller.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very similar issue: [Why controller does not work in UI-router of angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33119452/1679310)

The point here is:

> Controller always belongs to View, never to state.

Other words, to use same type of controller (but two instances for each view), we have to do that kind of declaration:

```
 $stateProvider.state('Home', {
    url: '/',

    // instead of this
    //controller: "HomeCtrl",

    views: {
      "a": {
        templateUrl: 'templates/a.html',
        controller: "HomeCtrl", // we need this
      },
      "b": {
        templateUrl: 'templates/b.html',
        controller: "HomeCtrl", // and also this
      }
    }
  });
```

In case, we want to share some stuff among many views, we need different technique than "same controller". See:

#### [How do I share $scope data between states in angularjs ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27696612/1679310)

Another insight, could be covered here:

#### [scope and controller instantiation with ui router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29107012/1679310)

And including typescript, there is a detailed description and example how all views/states could target some common `RootModel`

#### [Angular Digest cycle being ran but ng-bind value not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32917945/1679310)

Comment: I had seen, but it does not work
Example i use this: {{a}}

outside views (<div ui-view="a"></div>) a or b result is: {{a}} = empty string
inside views (<div ui-view="a"></div>)  a and b result is: {{a}} = {{a}}

outside, angular try to traslate {{a}} but into template no

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your comment. If you can create plunker with your issue, I am ready to assist. But in general - if you want Home state to have some outer view-template and then some inner-views - you should use absolute naming. There could be some hint for you http://stackoverflow.com/q/28800644/1679310

Comment: ok, resolved. I had seen that article. the problem is in controller definition:
.controller("name",["aaa",function(aaaa){}]) , the closing of the bracket square is not corret in my code.

but outside the <div ui-view="a"></div> how to use $scope?

Comment: Good to see you have a progress. And keep in mind - controller belongs to view not to state ;)

Comment: When HomeCtrl controller is specified in both views, do you wind up with 2 instances of the controller, or is the same instance shared?