# UI-Router not running controller when there is a view section

Tags: angularjs, templates, nested, angular-ui-router, state

I've  a very strange problem, it apparently seems that simple views template are preventing a controller to be executed, I can't understand why.
I've built a simple [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeE8pa?p=preview)
Code is here:

```
angular.module('plunker', ["ui.router"])
  .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/nested");
    $stateProvider
      .state('nested', {
        url: '/nested',
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.sayHi = 'Hi';
          this.sayHello = 'Hello';
        },
        controllerAs: 'dog',
        //If I comment the "views" section, controller runs correctly
        views: {
          'main': {
            template: 'MainContent'
          },
          'secondary': {
            template: 'SecondaryContent'
          }
        }
      })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
  })
```

html:

```
<div ui-view>
  <h1>{{dog.sayHello}}</h1>
  <h1>{{sayHi}}</h1>
  <p>Why no "hello" or "Hi" over here?</p>
  <div ui-view="main"></div>
  <div ui-view="secondary"></div>
</div>
```

If I comment out the "views" section in the state definition, controller runs correctly.

[edit]
Thanks to Radim, I resolved moving the controller definition in the views section:

```
                         views:{
                          '':{
                              controller: function ($scope) {
                                  this.page = 'ten';
                              },
                              controllerAs:'dog'
                          },
                          'main@nested':{
                              template:'MainContent'
                          },
                          'secondary@nested':{
                              template:'SecondaryContent'
                          }
                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check:

- [UI-Router Multiple Views Single Controller not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33134124/1679310)

The **`controller`** always belongs to **view**, not to *state*.

There is [an updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Dkzoh?p=preview)

```
.state('nested', {
    url: '/nested',
    //controller: function($scope) {
    //  $scope.sayHi = 'Hi';
    //  this.sayHello = 'Hello';
    //},
    //controllerAs: 'dog',
    //If I comment the "views" section, controller runs correctly
    views: {
      'main': {
        //template: 'MainContent', - let's use view, to consume dog.sayHello
        templateUrl: 'view2.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
          $scope.sayHi = 'Hi';
          this.sayHello = 'Hello';
        },
        controllerAs: 'dog',
      },
      'secondary': {
        template: 'SecondaryContent',
        controller: ...
      }
    }
```

check [the updated plunekr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Dkzoh?p=preview)

Comment: Good. Glad to see that my solution is working for you. You can accept the answer

Comment: I'm sorry, at the moment I don't see any accept button, if I see it I'll click it for sure

Comment: If you do not mind, I suggest to go through this very short and very informative tour http://stackoverflow.com/tour... it is really good to know how it works here. And if you have some spare time, this is also nice reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help. Good luck, sir ;) Enjoy SO