# controller undefined in named views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

Following works perfect.
In my application file app.js, i have states like

```
.state('nna.home',
{
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html'                
    }
})

//home.html is like

<script src="../controllers/home.js"></script>
<div class="container cf" ng-controller="home">

// my home.js is included correctly in all cases have code like
alert(2); // works
app.controller('home', function ($scope) {
    alert(2); // works
});
```

But as soon as I try to use named views like following. It stops routing

```
.state('nna.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'v1' : {
         templateUrl: 'home.html',
         controller: 'home',
         resolve: {
            deps: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
              return $ocLazyLoad.load('homecontroller.js');
            }
          }
      },
    }



// my home.js is included correctly in all cases have code like
alert(2); // works
app.controller('home', function ($scope) {
    alert(2); // Does not work
});
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/eGWVT3wTmvjG8r1oxJnY?p=preview)

**I can use them fine as long as i load all controller files in index** but i want to load controllers only with views not all the way in index

Probably the issue is with my understanding about named views, but i am stuck to know the reason that why the `home` is undefined even when i can show with alert that file had been successfully added

Comment: and do you have `<div ui-view="v1"></div>` in the parent template?

Comment: There is a clear explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33139917/1679310. And also here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33119575/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler,  Sorry but I could get nothing like clear from the two answers, regarding my question. And the question asks how to include/reference separate controller.js file that would have scope limited to that view only, when using named views

Comment: I created a plunker (working one) with your scenario. Find it in the answer section, hope it helps a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   .state('nna.home',
    {
        url: '/home',
        views: {
            'v1': {
                templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
                controller: 'home'
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: No Sorry.. Same Error

Answer (score 0):

There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tBRwqBVt8dPWptrvvV6?p=preview)

These could be the states:

```
.state('nna', {
    template: '<div ui-view="v1"></div>',
})
.state('nna.home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
      'v1' : {
         templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
         controller: 'home',
      },
    }
});
```

And these links are working now:

```
<a href="#/home">
<a ui-sref="nna.home">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4tBRwqBVt8dPWptrvvV6?p=preview)